# Can I use Amazon Certificate with my EC2 instance (website)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-certificate-manager

I have a website on EC2 instance, and I just created an Amazon certificate, but I am not sure that this is a regular SSL certificate.
All I wanted was to have the green padlock for my website (HTTPS).

Is the Amazon Certificate made to do that? Or it's for other purposes, and I should use another SSL, such as Let'sEncrypt?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only use an ACM certificate with specific AWS services (documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/acm-services.html)):

- Elastic Load Balancing
- Amazon CloudFront
- AWS Elastic Beanstalk
- Amazon API Gateway
- AWS CloudFormation

If you're hosting your website on EC2, you will need to set up either an ELB or CloudFront to use an ACM-managed certificate. If you don't want to do that (both are extra charges) then you'll need to use a certificate provided by someone else, such as Let's Encrypt.